# How should work with arrays of string in c

Tags: c, linux, arrays

I want to use an array of string  the same as this:

```
char arr[][20] = {"username1", "username2"};
```

after i have not problem to get values, for example :

```
printf("%s", arr[0]); // for "username1"
```

i have problem to insert new string to this array, something like this!? :

```
arr[2] = "username3"; // or sprintf(arr[2], "%s", "username3");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong way of doing this would be as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char arr[][20] = {"username1", "username2"};
    printf("%s\n", arr[0]);
    printf("%s\n", arr[1]);
    printf("sizeof arr : %d \n", sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));
    strcpy(arr[2],"username3");
    printf("%s\n", arr[2]);
    printf("sizeof arr : %d \n", sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));
    return 0;
}
```

because, when you write something like the below

```
char arr[][20] = {"username1", "username2"};
```

The first dimension is automatically calculated based on the given initializer, in this case, it is `2` (i.e. index `0` and `1`).

Later when you try to access (read or write), the third element i.e. index `2`, it is a undefined behavior.

If you want to increase the first dimension of a 2d array, the correct way of doing that would be as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 20

int main(void) 
{
    char **arr = NULL;
    int n=2, n1;
    int i;

    if ((arr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * n)) == NULL) {
        printf("unable to allocate memory \n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (i=0; i<n ; i++) {
        if ((arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * LEN)) == NULL) {
            printf("unable to allocate memory \n");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    strcpy(arr[0], "username1");
    strcpy(arr[1], "username2");

    printf("%s\n", arr[0]);
    printf("%s\n", arr[1]);

    /* add 5 more elements to arr */
    n1 = 5;

    if ((arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(char *) * (n + n1))) == NULL) {
        printf("unable to allocate memory \n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (i=n; i<n1+n ; i++) {
        if ((arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * LEN)) == NULL) {
            printf("unable to allocate memory \n");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    strcpy(arr[2], "username2");
    strcpy(arr[3], "username3");
    strcpy(arr[4], "username4");
    strcpy(arr[5], "username5");
    strcpy(arr[6], "username6");

    /* if you uncomment the below, it will lead to undefined behavior */
    //strcpy(arr[7], "username7");

    for (i=0; i<n+n1 ; i++)
        printf("%d : %s \n", i, arr[i]);

    for (i=0; i<n+n1 ; i++) 
        free(arr[i]);
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}

$ ./a.out 
username1
username2
0 : username1 
1 : username2 
2 : username2 
3 : username3 
4 : username4 
5 : username5 
6 : username6 
$
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to insert a `char*` into an array of `char[20]`. That won't work. You could use `strcpy` as

```
strcpy(arr[2], "username3");
```

**if** you had allocated sufficient space for a third string, which you haven't. I suggest you read up on `malloc` and friends; you can't just append a string to this array.

Answer (score 2):

With this static initialization, `arr` will not dynamically resize to hold a new entry (pointers to entries in the stack generally don't like being written to).

In order for this to work, `arr` should be of `char **` and allocated properly:

```
// allocate enough for three entries in arr
char **arr = (char **) malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
```

Answer (score 1):

C does not have dynamically growing data structures built-in. If you want an array that can hold an increasing number of elements, you need to involve dynamic memory allocation. This is usually done using the `realloc()` function, which can be used to allocate and then re-allocate a memory block, so that you can grow the allocation as needed.